# Insert two columns from different tables into one table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have two tables, one with user-ids and another with item-ids. There are repeated entries in both tables but that is required. There are 42,000 entries in both tables.

I need to merge these tables such that there are 42,000 entries in the third table "user-item" such that first column contains the user-ids and second column contains item-ids as is from the two previous tables.

> Userinfo table: (column is userid)

18974

41092

4287

41092 and so on

> Iteminfo table: (column is itemid)

13

182

13

76 and so on

> Required table:

Userid  | Itemid

18974   | 13

41092   | 182

4287    |  13

41092   | 76

and so on.

Comment: As always.. please, show your structure, sample sets and desired result. Please, show your approach, why it's not working and what you've expected.

Comment: _"They are both in order..."_ In SQL tables do not have an order.  You provide ordering in your query.  _"...such that user-id i selected item-id i"_ What does this mean?  If there are repeated entries in each table and no key with which to impose an unambiguous ordering, then whether or not users and items match up correctly will be entirely random at the whim of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you need this::

```
INSERT INTO thirdTable
Select ft.userId, st.itemId 
from firtTable ft
INNER JOIN secondTable st on (ft.userId = st.userId)
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I have repeated entries in the tables. Thus, if there are 'm' items that are repeated and 'n' that are unique entries, I get 'm^2+n' values in the resulting table, with spurious data. I solved this problem using _distinct_

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT 
   INTO thirdTable 
Select 
   f.userId, s.itemId 
from 
   firtTable f,
   secondTable s 
where 
   f.userId = s.userId
```